# How do you get git committer description for Jenkins pipeline

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, git-commit

I have a pipeline set up in groovy and need to pull the complete description committed some code in git so. I've searched the web and can't seem to find a solution. I can get the title committed but when it is very large I can't get it complete, because the title is cut off at a certain number of characters, the code that

I used is:
sh(script: 'git log --format:"%B"', returnStdout: true).trim()